# How to make my navigation bar work in Django?

Tags: python, html, css, django

I have created a simple website using django, html, css and python. Everything is working fine, but my navigation bar is not working.

I am getting this error:
[The error I am getting.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TPZmt.png)

This is my code below:

**prodj/urls.py:**

```py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path , include

urlpatterns = [
  path('',include('app1.urls')),
  path('morse',include('morse.urls')),
  path('binary',include('binary.urls')),
  path('ascii',include('ascii_con.urls')),
  path('admin/', admin.site.urls)
]
```

This is my homepage:
[My homepage pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rkzMz.png)

Only problem is that my navigation bar is not working, it shows the error mentioned in above image.

Comment: check the url you provided in that link. Have you defined binary.html?

Comment: add your navigation bar html code,

Comment: I have tried everything you said but I just doesnt work.

Answer (score 0):

As you attached "prodj/urls.py" file code, I am assuming this "urls.py" file is from the prodj app.
Then what is in your project level "urls.py" file? Would you provide the urlpatterns of that file please so that we might help you better.

The problem you are facing is because of the urlpatterns and the transitions between them.
From what can be seen in here you are probably missing an urlpattern for the prodj app in your project's "urls.py" file.